# Get all 24 hours in a sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime-generation

my question is how can I select all 24 hours in a day as data in a `select`?

There is a more polished way to do that:

```
select 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23
  from dual
```

My target db is `Mysql`, but a sql-standard solution is appreciated!

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question? I don't understand at all.

Comment: I think it would be better to include the use case if possible.

Answer (score 4):

MySQL doesn't have recursive functionality, so you're left with using the NUMBERS table trick -

1. Create a table that only holds incrementing numbers - easy to do using an auto_increment:

   ```
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `example`.`numbers`;
   CREATE TABLE  `example`.`numbers` (
     `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
   ```
2. Populate the table using:

   ```
   INSERT INTO NUMBERS
     (id)
   VALUES
     (NULL)
   ```

   ...for as many values as you need.  In this case, the INSERT statement needs to be run at least 25 times.
3. Use [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) to construct a list of hours, increasing based on the `NUMBERS.id` value:

   ```
   SELECT x.dt
     FROM (SELECT TIME(DATE_ADD('2010-01-01', INTERVAL (n.id - 1) HOUR)) AS dt
             FROM numbers n
            WHERE DATE_ADD('2010-01-01', INTERVAL (n.id - 1) HOUR) <= '2010-01-02' ) x
   ```

### Why Numbers, not Dates?

Simple - dates can be generated based on the number, like in the example I provided.  It also means using a single table, vs say one per data type.

Comment: Good answer but I thought MySQL had its own sequence generation function.

Comment: @jeff Moden: Do you have a link to what you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from dual WHERE field BETWEEN 0 AND 24
```

Comment: seems promising, but mysql says: #1096 - No tables used

Comment: can you give us the mysql table structure on which this query is applied ? it will be much clearer for us to give you a good answer, currently as a refference wee have only your select statement. thx